# Dropdown button on select disable some of second Dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have two drop down menus like this :

```
        <select name="start" class="form-control">
            {% for i in range(2000) %}
            <option value={{i}}>{{i}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        End
        <select name="end" class="form-control">
            {% for i in range(2000) %}
            <option value={{i}}>{{i}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

I can not have the start time be more than the end time, but unsure how I should do this.

Comment: can you show your current javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following ( assuming that all values are numbers):

```js
$('select[name="start"').change(function(){
  var year = $(this).val();
  $('select[name="end"] option').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).val()) < year;
  }).prop('disabled', true);
});
$('select[name="end"]').change(function(){
  var year = $(this).val();
  $('select[name="start"] option').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).val()) > year;
  }).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Start:
<select name="start" class="form-control">
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="600">600</option>
  <option value="700">700</option>
  <option value="800">800</option>
  <option value="900">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
End:
<select name="end" class="form-control">
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
  <option value="600">600</option>
  <option value="700">700</option>
  <option value="800">800</option>
  <option value="900">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```